# Creating an incremental number sequence in Java

Tags: java

So I'm creating a student database thing for a school project. My first issue is that upon creating a new student I should see "Application number ### has registered successfully". Now the problem is that we have to have that number generate (### referring to the number) sequentially from 1 every time a new application is recorded. How would I go about doing that?

So far this is what there is but I can't seem to get the number to generate incrementally.

```
public TestApplication(String Surname, String personalIdNo)
{
    if (isValidpersonalIdNo(personalIdNo) == true)
    {
        Student.add(Surname);
        Application.put(personalIdNo, Student);
        System.out.println("Application number ### " +  "has registered successfully");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Application has failed, Personal id: " + personalIdNo);
    }
}
```

Any help with this would be appreicated.

Comment: The most common approach for this would be to do it in the database. Most databases have the ability to have a column that is an auto-generated sequence number.  When you insert the record for the first time, the next incremental number is inserted in that column.

Comment: You're not entirely clear on whether you need to (re)invent a Java based database system yourself or that you have to use an existing (relational/SQL) database system. For the former, `AtomicLong` may be interesting. For the latter, just use DB-generated PK (in e.g. MySQL, check its documentation using keyword "auto_increment")

Comment: also a recommendation for you:  Use `String surName` (or `surname`).  Per java convention, instances should be camelCased.  Second, for your second parameter, use `int` or `Integer` for a numeric field.

Comment: How do you persist the recorded applications?

Comment: I highly recommend you learning object oriented language. `int applicationNumber = 0` as an instance variable. And then you can increment `applicationNumber++` on application registration method call.

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to be using lots of static methods, I believe the best thing for you to do in this case is to create a static field called *latestId* and a static method called *generateId*, both in the Student class. Then you can call the *generateId* method whenever you call *Student.add*.

However, please note that this solution does not work if your application is multithread.

```
public class Student {

private static int latestId = 0;

public static int generateId() {
   return ++latestId;
}

...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a singleton class that will produce the ids for you:

```
class Generator {

  private AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(1);
  private static Generator generator = new Generator();

  private Generator() { }
  public static Generator getInstance() {
    return generator;
  }

  public int generate() {
    return count.getAndIncrement();
  }

}
```

Now, when you need to get a new id, you just call the generate method. The `AtomicInteger` is used because you might need the id from multiple threads and it will make the concurrent access safe.

The singleton `Generator` provides a single entry point to the id-generating facility.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your storage type to give you the amount of added students that were put into DB.
I don't know what type you use to store your students. If it is hashmap or vector you can use size method to print students count. So I assume if you have Application.put you probably have a field in your Application type that is used to store each student. Then you can add a method like getStudentsCount to it and you should be all set. Since I don't know much about your Application type the above is all assumptions. Below you can find how I would solve that:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Vector;

class Student{
    private String name;
    private int personalID;
    public Student(String name, int personalID){
        this.name = name;
        this.personalID = personalID;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getPersonalID() {
        return personalID;
    }
    public void setPersonalID(int personalID) {
        this.personalID = personalID;
    }


}
class DB{
    private HashMap<Integer, Student> students = new HashMap<Integer, Student>();

    public boolean addStudent(Student student) {
        Integer studentId = new Integer(student.getPersonalID());
        if( !students.containsKey(studentId)){
            students.put(new Integer(studentId), student);
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;


    }

    public int getStudentCount() {
        return students.size();
    }
}

class Operations{
    DB db;
    public Operations(DB db){
        this.db = db;
    }
    public boolean addStudent(String name, int personalID){
        Student student = new Student(name, personalID);
        return db.addStudent( student );
    }
}
public class SimpleStudentDB {

    public static void main(String [] args){
        DB db = new DB();
        Operations operations = new Operations(db);
        if( operations.addStudent( "Jason", db.getStudentCount()+1) )
            System.out.println("Student added successfully. DB contains ###"+db.getStudentCount()+" elements");
        else
            System.out.println("Operation failed");
    }
}
```